# Differentiation question using the definition of a derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f\left(x\right)=x^2\cos\left(x\right)$ show that $f\left(x\right)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ using the definition of a derivative which is:

$$ \lim _{x \to x_0} \frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_0\right)}{x-x_0}.$$

My solution:
let $x_n\rightarrow 0 \: \text{as} \: n\rightarrow \infty$. Furthermore, $\frac{f\left(x_n\right)-f\left(0\right)}{x_n-0}=\frac{{x_n}^2\cos(x_n)-0}{x_n-0}= x_n\cos(x_n).$ I then bounded the sequence as follows.

$-1 \leq \cos(x_n)\leq 1$

$\implies -x_n \leq x_n\cos(x_n)\leq x_n$, and since  $x_n\rightarrow 0 \: \text{as} \: n\rightarrow \infty$, then $x_n\cos(x_n) \rightarrow 0 \: \text{as} \: n\rightarrow \infty.$

Therefore, $f'\left(0\right)$ exists and $f'\left(0\right)=0$.

My question is: is it necessary to bound the $\cos(x_n)$? Furthermore, is this a correct way to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, of cours it is necessary to bound $\cos$ Try replacing it with $1/x^3$ and repeat the reasoning. And yes, this is how to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed **sufficient** to bound $\cos(x_n)$ to get the desired result. Notice that if $g$ isn't bounded then $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x g(x)$ may not equal $0$ or even doesn't exist: take for example $g(x)=\frac1{x^2}$ and with $g(x)=\frac1{\sqrt[3]x}$ the limit is $0$ although $g$ isn't bounded.